# How to pass multiple objects of same type to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I would like to pass multiple objects of the same type from Startup to a Controller in ASP.NET Core 3.

My Controller constructor:

```
public RenderImageController(CloudQueue startRenderQueue, CloudQueue renderCompletedQueue)
{
    _startRenderQueue = startRenderQueue;
    _renderCompletedQueue = renderCompletedQueue;
}
```

I tried this in Startup:

```
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(CloudQueue), startRenderQueue);
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(CloudQueue), renderCompletedQueue);
```

But, it resulted in the same object (second one) being passed to my controller.

What is the best way to pass objects like this to my controller?

Comment: Inject `IEnumerable<CloudQueue>` and extract the desired types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create one wrapper class for two cloudqueue and inject as singleton

```
    public interface IMyCloudQueueCollection
    {
        CloudQueue StartRenderQueue { get; }

        CloudQueue RenderCompletedQueue { get; }
    }

    public class MyCloudQueueCollection : IMyCloudQueueCollection
    {
        public CloudQueue StartRenderQueue { get; private set; }

        public CloudQueue RenderCompletedQueue { get; private set; }

        public MyCloudQueueCollection(CloudQueue startRenderQueue, CloudQueue renderCompletedQueue)
        {
            this.StartRenderQueue = startRenderQueue;
            this.RenderCompletedQueue = renderCompletedQueue;
        }
    }
     // in startup
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IMyCloudQueueCollection,MyCloudQueueCollection>(s=> new MyCloudQueueCollection(startRenderQueue, renderCompletedQueue))
    } 

     //in controller
     public RenderImageController(IMyCloudQueueCollection queueCollection)
     {
         _startRenderQueue = queueCollection.StartRenderQueue;
         _renderCompletedQueue = queueCollection.RenderCompletedQueue;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject `IEnumerable<CloudQueue>` into the controller constructor and extract the desired object

```
//...

public RenderImageController(IEnumerable<CloudQueue> queues) {    
    _startRenderQueue = queues.FirstOrDefault(queue => queue.Name == "startRenderQueueNameHere");
    _renderCompletedQueue = queues.FirstOrDefault(queue => queue.Name == "renderCompletedQueueNameHere");
}

//...
```

While the above example used the queue's `Name` to distinguish the desired object, You can use any one or combination of the other properties of the queue to identify it.